# SpringMVC Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have some problems in spring MVC Web

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/Volumes/Data/Obasy/Computer Science/Java projects/Netbeans/WEB APPS/SpringMVCFrom/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/com/tutorialspoint/HelloWorldController.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org/springframework/core/type/classreading/AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor
>
> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org/springframework/core/type/classreading/AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor

Comment: How are you managing your dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post your config files. Otherwise its hard to determine what exactly caused the problem.

A controller class should be annotated with @Controller, like this

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController() {
 ...
}
```

and the Spring MVC config should have a component scan either through XML

```
<context:component-scan base-package="package.of.helloworldcontroller" />
```

or through Java config

```
@Config
@ComponentScan(basePackage = {"package.of.helloworldcontroller"})
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if `HelloWorldController.class` with annotation.
For example:

```
@Component
public class HelloWorldController(){
 ...
}
```

And check in your context file, if the back-package includes the class

```
<context:component-scan base-package="xxx.xxx.xxx" />
```

And recompile your project and try again.